# J2ME Polish - List and TextField

Tags: j2mepolish

I am sorry for my bad English, but I am from Czech Republic. Thanks for understand.

Hi, 
 I am programming simple calculator in J2ME Polish. I created buttons by using object List (J2ME Polish, template accessible) and now I need put in display some textfield for typing terms. But I do not know how I do that. Object List does not support this:

myList.append(myTextField);

So I have all buttons and now I only need some TextField, but it is problem for me. 
 Thanks for any help. Peter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a List you should trying using a [Form](http://www.enough.de/javadoc/j2me/de/enough/polish/ui/Form.html). This would allow you to append the TextField at the start and ether create a [TableItem](http://www.enough.de/javadoc/j2me/de/enough/polish/ui/TableItem.html) of possible buttons you can press or use various [StringItem](http://www.enough.de/javadoc/j2me/de/enough/polish/ui/StringItem.html) objects and clever styling, such as the [midp2 view-type](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/lush-ui/visual-guide-to-item-views/gui-viewtype-midp2.html).

If I was creating a calculator I would try to use the midp2 view-type approach. This will mean the buttons will scale across the width of the screen. In terrible untested sudo-like code I might do:

```
//#style calcForm
Form calc = new Form( Locale.get( "calc.title" )); // See the use of J2ME Polish's [Localization][5]
calc.append( myInputField );
calc.append( plusOperator );
...
```

Where the css for the style might be:

```
/* Simple white to black gradient background, using midp2 view type styling */
.calcForm {
    padding: 2;
    padding-left: 10;
    padding-right: 10;
    background {
        type: vertical-gradient; /* See how I have added a little gradient background here*/
            top-color: red;
            bottom-color: black;
           start: 25%;
           end: 100%;
    }
    layout: horizontal-expand | horizontal-center | vertical-center;
    view-type: midp2;
}
```

Using the TableItem method will mean the buttons may not always fit on smaller screens, but you might it find quicker to implement. In terrible untested sudo-like code I might do:

```
    TableItem calcButtons = new TableItem(4, 4); //16 block table 4 by 4
    calcButtons.add(0,0, "1");                    //Don't trust my 0,0 indexing I sometimes forget
    ....
    calcButtons.addCommand(selectButton);
    calcButtons.setItemCommandListener( myViewObj ); //Or whatever is managing the object, it could be the MIDlet

Form calc = new Form( Locale.get("calc.title"));
...
calc.append(calcButtons);
...
```

Anyway I hope that you find some of this useful and that you can see how some of the other J2ME Polish features work.